# VSTO integration in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, vsto

I want to implement VSTO word integration in web application mvc3, like google docs. Is it possible to update word document online ? through VSTO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSTO enables you to run your code inside MS Office applications, such as Word, Excel, etc. and integrate your application with Office's features. However, this includes only desktop Office applications, which do not expose any web UI.

Comment: Thanks Marek for quick reply, Is there any way , i can use MS word online like google docs(update document online) ?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. I think the best approach to solve your problem would be to find some third-party control. There are a lot of companies that sell such controls, however, I'm not really familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

VSTO is not designed to be used in web applications. It introduces a dependency on MS Office which is not a server side application.

Comment: Thanks Darin for quick reply, Is there any way , i can use MS word online like google docs(update document online) ?

Answer (score 1):

VSTO can not used in web application.

Comment: Thanks guokexin for quick reply, Is there any way , i can use MS word online like google docs(update document online) ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint and SharePoint Online is there for your purpose.