# OpenXML SDK WordprocessingDocument display in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm currently trying this:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileNameDocx as string, true))
{
      var xdoc = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

      mainWebBrowser.NavigateToString(xdoc.Document.OuterXml.ToString());
}
```

But this just gives me the text and none of the formatting.  Is it possible to show a ".docx" in a webbrowser control like this?

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681035/vsto-integration-in-asp-net-web-application and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some articles related to DOCX to HTML converition:

- [Transforming Open XML WordprocessingML to XHTML Using the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628051%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Transforming Open XML WordprocessingML to XHtml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/20/eric-white-s-blog-s-table-of-contents.aspx#Open_XML_to_XHtml)
- [Batch conversion of docx to clean HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824619/batch-conversion-of-docx-to-clean-html)

Please try these approaches above. 
Hope that helps

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I found this solution too.  However I think I am going about my problem the wrong way by trying to use the OpenXML SDK.  I have Word 2010 installed on the machine that will be doing this and there is not much difference between this solution and just saving as HTML.  Thanks.

Comment: Saving as HTML requires to have MS Word installed on computer where your application is being executed. So in this case you will have a dependancy to MS Word. Transforming OpenXML to HTML - is more complex, but this code will be able to work on computer with no MS Word installed.

Comment: Correct, I do have a dependency on Word.  But since I know Word will be installed, this won't be a problem.

Comment: If you can get this to work and end up with clean HTML, you can then Convert the clean HTML to pdf using iTextSharp, thus creating a WordToPDF converter without using interop

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to show XML in web browser control, you might need to:

1. load this XML to [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx),
2. prepare HTML template with  [block](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pre),
3. and then - write [formatted XML from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374654/how-do-you-create-an-indented-xml-string-from-an-xdocument-in-c) into PRE block.

You could either read the final HTML into string and use 'mainWebBrowser.NavigateToString' as you mentioned, or write HTML file to drive and read it from there into your mainWebBrowser

Hope that helps

Comment: I was actually hoping the document would display with the actual DOCX Word formatting, possibly using XSLT styles.  That is not the case though.  I also tried loading this into an XDocument. Also if any images are embedded into the document, for them to show also.